# Whats an intuitive interface for managing user groups and permissions?

Tags: forms, interaction-design

I am building a web app with an admin interface for editing users, groups and permissions. Currently, the interface looks like this:

http://cl.ly/3I0l1B1e2x092g0s3q1B

To remove a permission from a group or a user from a group, the user has to cmd-click (or ctrl click) to deselect and then hit save.

Can anyone recommend a more intuitive / elegant way to do this?

Comment: ctrl click is usually for selecting multiple rather than deleting, so it's good that you are exploring other design options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a dual-multiselect control like this:

[image: Dual-multiselect]

This would depend on how many users you have though. Dual multiselect might actually work better for groups, and this would be another option for users if you have a lot of them:
[image: user list]

Clicking the + button would bring up a modal dialog that includes a list of all of your users to select from, and perhaps search options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This jQuery plugin looks like it will do the job. I could then go modal for the add user form. http://nmultiselect.ndesoft.dk/

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using a control other than a multi-select box. Using a **list of checkboxes** seems like a pretty safe choice for the context you present in your screenshot:

[image]

This will help make selection (and de-selection) direct and obvious instead of requiring a fairly advanced "CTRL + click" interaction from the user.

Comment: I agree this is a solid choice. Thanks for your reply.